# If in Where Clause Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

My table looks like as show below
I have a query which counts OrderType data with matching with `OrderType` Column.Suppose i set variable to 'Delivery' it returns me 2 ,I want if i pass 'All' which is not in column it returns me all the data of full column.Guide me how to get all data .For demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcff9/2

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yuck for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to return all the `OrderType` and `COUNT` for all records, just add `OR @argument = 'All'` to your SQL query:

```
SELECT OrderType, COUNT(OrderType) AS [Count]
FROM [Order]
WHERE OrderType = @argument
OR @argument = 'All'
GROUP BY OrderType
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e718

If you mean that you'd like to just return one row `All` with the a sum of everything, though, then it gets to be a little trickier:

```
SELECT
  CASE @argument
    WHEN 'All' THEN 'ALL'
    ELSE OrderType
  END [OrderType],
  COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [Order]
WHERE OrderType = @argument
  or @argument = 'All'
GROUP BY
  CASE @argument
    WHEN 'All' THEN 'ALL'
    ELSE OrderType
  END
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e718/5

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your where clause:

```
or (@argument='All' and 1=1)
```

It will use your initial 'OrderType = @argument' but if @argument is 'All' then it will show everything.